# how to send email as group name address by lotus domino

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I have a questions, how to send email as group name address by lotus domino?
Is it possible to send email as group name address by Lotus Domino 8.5.3? I have created a group with members, but I want to send e-mail as group address/name. Multi purpose group? Maybe mail-in database? How is this configured?:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that in an easy way from the mailbox.
Notes/Domino will set the sender in the email header to the person actually sending the email.
You can write Lotusscript code where you set a different sender address, but that requires an undocumented way to do it, by injecting the mail document directly into mail.box.

I wrote a Lotusscript class a few years ago where I utilize that method.
http://blog.texasswede.com/updated-mailnotification-class-now-with-html-email-support-and-web-links/